# Issues with core data persisting when making changes to entities

Tags: swift, core-data

I have features to delete and edit my core data entities via the UI. Although the changes work in the UI, they are not persisted when returning to the view. I am sure I have missed something thats causing no save to take place, but cant figure it out. Is it just a case of adding the standard save throw and catch to the end of the delete function? As that gives me unwrapping errors unless ? or ! are used

I have included the switch case for the functions an example:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch (type) {
    case .insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
            workoutDesignerTable.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break;
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            workoutDesignerTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break;
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let cell = workoutDesignerTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? RoutineTableViewCell {
            configure(cell, at: indexPath)
        }
        break;
    default:
        print("...")
    }
}
```

the delete func

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Fetch Exercise
        let UserExercise = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        // Delete Exercise
        UserExercise.managedObjectContext?.delete(UserExercise)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let UserExercise = fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        UserExercise.delete(fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
        do {
                try UserExercise.save()
        } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```